# Variable value not accumulating?

Tags: javascript

Hey I'm very new to JS but cannot figure out why the 3 variables at the top aren't accumulating?

```
var xe = 0;
var reckon = 0;
var books = 0;


document.getElementById('#go').addEventListener('click', function(){
questionOne();
});
document.getElementById('#macos').addEventListener('click',function(){
  addXe();
  questionThree();
});
document.getElementById('#windows').addEventListener('click',function(){
  questionThree();
});
document.getElementById('#linux').addEventListener('click', function(){
  questionThree();
});
document.getElementById('#large').addEventListener('click', function(){
  questionFour();
  addXe();
});



function addXe(){
  xe++;
};
function addReckon(){
  reckon++;
};
function addBooks(){
  books++;
};
```

The rest of the code is simply a series of functions that toggles divs display on and off.
If Ive missed and important info out let me know,
Thanks!

EDIT:

github.com/daffron/accountingsoftware

I thought it would be easier to attach the whole site, the problem is each time the addXero function is executed , it doesn't accumulate the value of var xero, I have it printing to console in the other functions. Thanks –

Comment: what is the issue/error

Comment: where you used those variables? and what are `questionFour` and `questionThree`

Comment: Where are you checking the incremented value

Comment: Hey, Have edited the original question with these answers

Answer (score 3):

Your parameters for `document.getElementById()` are wrong. 
If your HTML code for a button is like this:

```
<input type="button" id="go" />
<!-- OR like this: -->
<button id="go" ></button>
```

Then your javascript code must access the button using the method `getElementById()` as:

```
document.getElementById("go");
```

So, one of your functions will be like:

```
document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', function(){
questionOne();
});
```

BUT, if you've used '#go' because you were referring to a CSS Selector then you've to use `querySelector` method instead of `getElementById`as:

```
document.querySelector("#go");
```

So, a function call as per your code will be:

```
  document.querySelector('#go').addEventListener('click', function(){
    questionOne();
    });
```

Comment: Or use `document.querySelector()` which uses CSS selectors like `#go`

Comment: Made necessary changes as per Andreas's suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Thanks, 
but that part of the program was working correctly.
https://github.com/daffron/accountingsoftware
I thought it would be easier to attach the whole site, the problem is each time the addXero function is executed , it doesn't accumulate the value of var xero, I have it printing to console in the other functions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should have html label example

```
<label id="xeLbl">test</label>
```

and after changing value you should apply it to html label.

```
function addXe(){
  xe++;
  document.getElementById('xeLbl').innerHTML = xe;
};
```